# Stopping mariadb service without stopping/restarting mariadb container

Tags: docker, mariadb

im trying to stop maridb service, im using mysqld stop inside shell command in container but it wont work, im using mariadb https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb and Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57

```
root@9eb7765a7f47:/# mysqld stop
2022-01-21  9:57:47 0 [Note] mysqld (server 10.6.5-MariaDB-1:10.6.5+maria~focal) starting as process 72 ...
2022-01-21  9:57:47 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
mysqld: Please consult the Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2022-01-21  9:57:47 0 [ERROR] Aborting
root@9eb7765a7f47:/#
```

im enter the shell using this docker command :

```
docker exec -it 9eb7765a7f47 /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

For most purposes a Docker container *is* the main process running in the container; if you stop the process, the container stops too.  In the same way you don't "go inside" a database process and stop individual threads, you don't usually "go inside" a Docker container to manage processes; in most cases there will be only one.

I'd suggest reserving `docker exec` for exceptional situations: it's a very useful debugging tool, but not the normal way to manage a container.  I'd also never leave a container in "stopped" state.  It's very normal to delete and recreate a container and that's what I'd recommend here.

```sh
docker stop 9eb7765a7f47
docker rm 9eb7765a7f47
docker run -d -p3306:3306 --name mysql -v ... mysql
```